# How can I override path to my alternate template (.tpl.php) file, located within my module's folder?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I want to create a custom theme for a specific page. (e.g. www.domain.com/roster/%/home) For this purpose I've created the following file and placed it within the templates folder of my current theme (bartik): page--roster--home.tpl.php.

It overrides the default theme as desired, but I want to keep all files related to my module within its folder.

My question is, how can I place the file within my module's folder and still have Drupal 7 pick it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Theme()

```
return theme('some_theme_function_template', array('aValues' => $someArray));
```

Then you need to use the theme hook like this:

```
function my_module_name_theme() {
    return array(
        'some_theme_function_template' => array(
            'template' => 'mytheme',
        ),
    );
}
```

It now searches for mytheme.tpl.php in the root of you're module.

Comment: Thank Jurgo! I haven't been able to test your implementation yet, but I will be able this weekend. It looks good, and when I try it out I'll post another comment.

Comment: As it turned out, my priorities shifted that week and I had to move onto other things. I've recently got back to this and was able to successfully implement the Theme() function. Thanks for the help, Jurgo!